# My clojure function works when defined in the repl but not when loaded from a script

Tags: clojure

I am using Clojure 1.4.0 on Windows XP (JVM=1.6.0).

My `help.clj` script contains obscure snippets of Clojure code that I find useful.

In the Clojure `repl` I can access it from the current directory with `(load-file "help.clj")`.

Trying to be fancy I write `(defn clojure-help [] (load-file "help.clj"))`. Now a simple `(clojure-help)` loads it.

Then I tried putting the `clojure-help` function in a `repl` startup script I use.

But now calling `(clojure-help)` results in the following Exception:

`CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: clojure-help in this context`

What am I missing?

Comment: What is your startup script like? How do you start the repl? It looks like the `defn` is simply not being evaluated.

Comment: Here is my startup script `prompt.clj` ->

    `(defn my-prompt [] (printf "\n[%s]> " (ns-name *ns*)))
      (defn p1 [] (clojure.main/repl :prompt my-prompt))
        (p1)
    
    (defn closure-help [] (load-file "help.clj"))`

It starts on the command line. `java -cp clojure-1.4.0.jar clojure.main prompt.clj` The `my-prompt` function works ok.

Comment: Sorry everybody. I spelled `clojure` with an `s` (`closure`!)

Comment: Thanks opqdonut. You were right, my `defn` was not being evaluated and @DaoWen shows why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for posting the code in the comments above! Without the code it's impossible to know what's actually going on. Making one simple change seems to fix the problem:

```
(defn my-prompt [] (printf "\n[%s]> " (ns-name *ns*)))

(defn p1 [] (clojure.main/repl :prompt my-prompt))

(defn clojure-help [] (load-file "help.clj"))

(p1)
```

The change was moving the `(p1)` call to the *end* of the script. If the call isn't at the end of the script then Clojure drops into the REPL before evaluating the rest of the functions in the script, and thus they are not available in the REPL. Since `clojure-help` was defined *after* the `(p1)` call in your script it was not being evaluated until after exiting the REPL.

Comment: Thanks DaoWen, that solved it. I am new to Clojure so your advice is very valuable. I am used to Python where compilation order is not so important.

Comment: @exbctel - I'm glad you've decided to try out Clojure! Since both Clojure and Python are compiled/interpreted line-by-line I'm pretty sure code similar to what you have above would have caused an error in Python too. When I run `print f() <<newline>> def f(): return 5` it throws an error saying that `f` is not defined. In contrast, Java does two passes over the code while compiling in order to do forward-resolution, so calling a method declared later in a file isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using the repl to load other scripts you could do something like this:

```
clojure --init replstartup.clj --repl
```

Where replstartup.clj would contain your closure-help function.

Alternatively you could just create a batch file, named clojure-repl.bat (or some such thing) that looks like this.

```
@echo off
java -cp %userprofile%\clojure-1.4.0.jar clojure.main --init repl-startup.clj --repl
@echo on
```